# How to Fetch from my local host? Connect React.js to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Creating my first MERN application and connected the frontend to the backend.

Taking baby steps and trying to simply call the already existing "books" in my mongo database.

Heres what I have

```
 const fetchingFunction = () => {

   fetch('http://localhost:5000/books', {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       'Accept': 'application/json'
     }
   }).then(function(response) {

      response.json();

   }).then(data => console.log(data))

 }
```

I keep getting the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the `response.json()`.

```
 const fetchingFunction = () => {

   fetch('http://localhost:5000/books', {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       'Accept': 'application/json'
     }
   }).then(function(response) {

      return response.json();

   }).then(data => console.log(data))

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `response.json()` will solve your problem